# Upload Image to MySQL server from Android Studio

Tags: php, android, mysql, http-post

I am trying to upload an image to a MySQL database and I am getting a message from PHP saying that the image has been uploaded, but when I log into my server the value is `NULL`. The Image is uploaded in my running app but its name or path cannot be added. Kindly, how can I solve this problem?

```
<?php
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') {
        $pet_image=$_POST['pet_image'];
        $sql = "INSERT INTO pet_info (pet_image) VALUES (?)";
                
        $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn,$sql);
                
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"s",$pet_image);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
                
        $check = mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt);
                
        if($check!=0){
            echo "Image Uploaded Successfully";
        } else {
            echo "Error Uploading Image";
        }
    }
?>
```

My Activity.java

```
    public class RequestHandler {
        public String sendGetRequest(String uri) {
            try {
                URL url = new URL(uri);
                HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
                String result;
    
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();   
                while ((result = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(result);
                }
                return sb.toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return null;
            }
        }
    
        public String sendPostRequest(String requestURL,
                                      HashMap<String, String> postDataParams) {
            URL url;
            String response = "";
            try {
                url = new URL(requestURL);
    
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setReadTimeout(15000);
                conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setDoInput(true);
                conn.setDoOutput(true);
    
    
                OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                        new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
                writer.write(getPostDataString(postDataParams));
    
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
                os.close();
                int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
    
                if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                   BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                    response = br.readLine();
                } else {
                    response = "Error Registering";
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return response;
        }
    
        private String getPostDataString(HashMap<String, String> params) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            boolean first = true;
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()) {
                if (first)
                    first = false;
                else
                    result.append("&");
    
                result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
                result.append("=");
                result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
            }
            return result.toString();
        }
            
        private void showFileChooser() {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
        }
    
        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, 
                                        int resultCode, Intent data) {
           super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    
            if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
                Uri filePath = data.getData();
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);
                setToImageView(bitmap);
                //pet_image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
        }
        
        private void setToImageView(Bitmap bmp) {
            //compress image
            ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
            Bitmap decoded = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new 
                                 ByteArrayInputStream(bytes.toByteArray()));
            pet_image.setImageBitmap(decoded);
        }
       
        public String getStringImage(Bitmap bmp){
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
            byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
            String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
            return encodedImage;
        }

        private void uploadImage() {
            class UploadImage extends AsyncTask<Bitmap, Void, String> {
    
                ProgressDialog loading;
                RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();
    
                @Override
                protected void onPreExecute() {
                    super.onPreExecute();
                    loading = ProgressDialog.show(My_pet.this, "Saving....", "Please wait...", true, true);
                }
    
                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                    super.onPostExecute(s);
                    loading.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
    
                @Override
                protected String doInBackground(Bitmap... params) {
                    Bitmap bitmapp = params[0];
                    String uploadImage = getStringImage(bitmapp);
    
                    HashMap<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();
                    data.put(UPLOAD_KEY, uploadImage);
    
                    String result = rh.sendPostRequest(UPLOAD_URL, data);
    
                    return result;
                }
            }
            UploadImage ui = new UploadImage();
            ui.execute(bitmap);
        }
   }
```

Comment: Do not store images in SQL; store image on server and add image path to sql table

Comment: @Shubham Srivastava This question should be answered as it is asked, where to store the images is a separate design consideration.

Comment: @Elletlar If they had written it as an answer, sure, but noting better practice in comments seems valid and appropriate.

Comment: @Jonnix "Noting" best practises?  "Do not store images in SQL" -> Command, not a suggestion.

Comment: @Elletlar That's a non-argument. By the same account your comment could be considered a command, but since you have no way of enforcing that, it's a suggestion / opinion. Comments should be taken as such, comments, nothing more. The initial comment imo can be construed as "this is what you should actually be doing imo", which, also imo, is correct, you shouldn't really store image data in a database without a valid use case (which is rare in my experience). Feel free to disagree, it's a matter of opinion :).

Comment: @Jonnix "this is what you should [consider] doing" -> It should have been expressed as such with good manners and in accordance with StackOverflow's policy on being friendly towards new users. As far as the question, it is a valid technical exercise whether the solution is appropriate for a scalable commercial project or not.

Comment: @ShubhamSrivastava please sir, can you share a link for how can I do this?

Comment: @Dina Gamal You just need to save file somewhere can be same machine or other storage solutions available and then just save the path of image in string column in sql

Comment: @ShubhamSrivastava sorry , how can I save the path every time I tried to save the path of the image the result is null in the MySQL table

Comment: @DinaGamal Lets say you create a folder on image upload save the image to folder then lets say your path is '\image'; So now you can save the image path like '/image/img_001.jpg' in DB; Now when you need to access this file just get path and fetch image from this folder

Comment: I tried to do this but in the image folder the image size is empty
file_put_contents($ImagePath,base64_decode($ImageData));
ImageData is my post image and ImagePath is the base of my image that will be saved in MySQL table